# how to serialize manually a class?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I want to serialize my class. I have this code :

```
public class Video implements Serializable{
public long videoId;
public String title;
public String publisher;
public String language;
public Date lastModified;
public Date published;
public String imageUrl;
public String url;
public Bitmap myVideoScreenshotBm;
//public Drawable myVideoScreenshotDrawable;

public CedemoVideo (long newVideoId) {
    this.videoId=newVideoId;
}
```

}

As far I have check i'm getting a NotSerializableException because of the Bitmap variable.

I apparently need to implement :

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

Anyone know what I should do in these function ?? How should I write my Bitmap variable ?Any code examples ? anyone did it ?

Answer (score 1):

While serializing the bitmap variable, just **serialize the url of the bitmap**. Deserialization should make use of this url to construct the actual bitmap field.

Comment: Well, its exactly what im trying to avoid. I dont want to redownload the bitmap from internet. I want to save it and restore it when i need. How do I write a Bitmap object to an ObjectOutputStream ?

Comment: Consider converting the bitmap to an array of bytes. Upon deserialization,read the byte array from the file system and construct the bitmap. Possible in android?

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628016/android-how-to-save-a-bitmap-buggy-code