# Android how to save a bitmap - buggy code

Tags: android, serialization, bitmap, save

I'm trying to serialize a class in which I have a bitmap variable. Here is the code that is a bit working. I need help to find out what is still wrong.

```
private Bitmap myVideoScreenshotBm;

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    
    out.writeInt(myVideoScreenshotBm.getRowBytes());
    out.writeInt(myVideoScreenshotBm.getHeight());
    out.writeInt(myVideoScreenshotBm.getWidth());
    
    int bmSize = myVideoScreenshotBm.getHeight() * myVideoScreenshotBm.getRowBytes();
    ByteBuffer dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
    
    myVideoScreenshotBm.copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
    
    byte[] bytesar=new byte[bmSize];
    dst.position(0);
    dst.get(bytesar);
    
    out.write(bytesar);
    
    
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    
    int nbRowBytes=in.readInt();
    int height=in.readInt();
    int width=in.readInt();
    //
    int bmSize = nbRowBytes * height;
    byte[] toread= new byte[bmSize];
    
    in.read(toread, 0, toread.length);
    ByteBuffer dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
    dst.put(toread);
    dst.position(0);
    myVideoScreenshotBm=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    myVideoScreenshotBm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(dst);
    
}
```

I'm not getting an error, but the bitmaps I'm getting are wrong. Also, I do not know how to know which Bitmap.Config flag is suitable. How can I know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the code for a serialization with memory optimisation. Im using a static buffer that is growing to the biggest bitmap size and that I reuse each time.

```
public class Video implements Serializable{
public long videoId;
public String title;
public String publisher;
public String language;
public Date lastModified;
public Date published;
public String imageUrl;
public String url;
public Bitmap myVideoScreenshotBm;
public Date expireTime;
//public Drawable myVideoScreenshotDrawable;

private static ByteBuffer dst;
private static byte[] bytesar;

public Video (long newVideoId) {
    this.videoId=newVideoId;
}
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{

    out.writeLong(videoId);

    out.writeObject(title);
    out.writeObject(publisher);
    out.writeObject(language);
    out.writeObject(lastModified);
    out.writeObject(published);
    out.writeObject(expireTime);

    out.writeObject(imageUrl);
    out.writeObject(url);


    out.writeInt(myVideoScreenshotBm.getRowBytes());
    out.writeInt(myVideoScreenshotBm.getHeight());
    out.writeInt(myVideoScreenshotBm.getWidth());

    int bmSize = myVideoScreenshotBm.getRowBytes() * myVideoScreenshotBm.getHeight();
    if(dst==null || bmSize > dst.capacity())
        dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);

    out.writeInt(dst.capacity());

    dst.position(0);

    myVideoScreenshotBm.copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
    if(bytesar==null || bmSize > bytesar.length)
        bytesar=new byte[bmSize];

    dst.position(0);
    dst.get(bytesar);


    out.write(bytesar, 0, bytesar.length);

}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    videoId=in.readLong();

    title=(String) in.readObject();
    publisher=(String) in.readObject();
    language=(String) in.readObject();
    lastModified=(Date) in.readObject();
    published=(Date) in.readObject();
    expireTime=(Date) in.readObject();

    imageUrl = (String) in.readObject();
    url = (String) in.readObject();


    int nbRowBytes=in.readInt();
    int height=in.readInt();
    int width=in.readInt();

    int bmSize=in.readInt();



    if(bytesar==null || bmSize > bytesar.length)
        bytesar= new byte[bmSize];


    int offset=0;

    while(in.available()>0){
        offset=offset + in.read(bytesar, offset, in.available());
    }


    if(dst==null || bmSize > dst.capacity())
        dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
    dst.position(0);
    dst.put(bytesar);
    dst.position(0);
    myVideoScreenshotBm=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    myVideoScreenshotBm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(dst);
    //in.close();
}
```

}

Comment: I am a newbie in the Java/Android world and I have implemented your sample code for my class. It also has some properties of primitive types, and a Bitmap type property. However, in the readObject method I get an OptionalDataException when I tried to read the first property, ie. "imageSource = (String) in.readObject();"

I have no idea why this is happening - any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: I only see two reasons possibles. First, the Exception itself tell you : "Signals that the ObjectInputStream class encountered a primitive type (int, char etc.) instead of an object instance in the input stream."

Comment: Second. May be you are not reading the data in the same order that you wrote them in the serialized object. Be carefull to respect the order... first wrote, first to be read.

Comment: This worked fine for me, except for the issue I ran into here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442761/objectinputstream-readbyte-int-int-missing-data.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

No need to have the redundant array + all the logic around + use the given methods to manipulate the buffer + utf is better for strings and avoid the casts + synchronization (but it is not thread safe anyway) :

```
private synchronized void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(title);
    out.writeUTF(url_friendly_name);
    out.writeUTF(creator_name);
    out.writeUTF(version);
    out.writeUTF(package_name);
    out.writeUTF(contact_website);
    out.writeInt(popularity);
    out.writeUTF(inconditional_redirect == null ? "" : inconditional_redirect);
    out.writeUTF(custom_description == null ? "" : custom_description);

    out.writeInt(icon.getRowBytes());
    out.writeInt(icon.getHeight());
    out.writeInt(icon.getWidth());
    out.writeInt(icon.getConfig().ordinal());

    final int bmSize = icon.getRowBytes() * icon.getHeight();
    if (dst == null || bmSize > dst.capacity()) {
        dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
    }
    dst.rewind();
    icon.copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
    dst.flip();
    out.write(dst.array(), 0, bmSize);
}


private synchronized void readObject(final ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    title = in.readUTF();
    url_friendly_name = in.readUTF();
    creator_name = in.readUTF();
    version = in.readUTF();
    package_name = in.readUTF();
    contact_website = in.readUTF();
    popularity = in.readInt();
    inconditional_redirect = in.readUTF();
    custom_description = in.readUTF();

    final int nbRowBytes = in.readInt();
    final int height = in.readInt();
    final int width = in.readInt();
    final Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.values()[in.readInt()];

    final int bmSize = nbRowBytes * height;
    if (dst == null || bmSize > dst.capacity()) {
        dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
    }
    dst.rewind();
    in.read(dst.array(), 0, bmSize);

    icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
    icon.copyPixelsFromBuffer(dst);
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me, except for the issue I ran into here - stackoverflow.com/questions/10442761/…. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

To simplify things, you can use standard serialization for all fields other than the bitmap.  Just mark the bitmap as transient, and use out.defaultWriteObject(); and in.defaultReadObject();.  This really cleans up the code:

```
private String title;
private String description;
private transient Bitmap icon;

private synchronized void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream out)
    throws IOException {
  // Serialize everything but the image
  out.defaultWriteObject();

  // Now serialize the image
  out.writeInt(icon.getRowBytes());
  out.writeInt(icon.getHeight());
  out.writeInt(icon.getWidth());
  out.writeInt(icon.getConfig().ordinal());

  final int bmSize = icon.getRowBytes() * icon.getHeight();
  if (dst == null || bmSize > dst.capacity()) {
    dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
  }
  dst.rewind();
  icon.copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
  dst.flip();
  out.write(dst.array(), 0, bmSize);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
  // Read everything but the image
  in.defaultReadObject();

  // Now read the image
  final int nbRowBytes = in.readInt();
  final int height = in.readInt();
  final int width = in.readInt();
  final Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.values()[in.readInt()];

  final int bmSize = nbRowBytes * height;
  if (dst == null || bmSize > dst.capacity()) {
    dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
  }
  dst.rewind();
  in.read(dst.array(), 0, bmSize);

  icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
  icon.copyPixelsFromBuffer(dst);
}
```