# User data not inserted to recyclerView after using activityForResult

Tags: java, android

I'm trying add some user data through add button and StartACtivityForResult. user data include name and bitmap for profile and gender . but in LogIn activity when I transfer data using putExtra of a Serializable class exist a problem . I get image from gallery and change to bitmap . data not added to my recyclerView . can anyone help?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alarmdrug, PID: 24413
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.alarmdrug.model.ModelPerson)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1850)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1797)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:945)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1584)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1253)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1014)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:11155)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.finishActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:4775)
    at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:6283)
    at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:6307)
    at com.example.alarmdrug.activities.LogIn.onLoginButtonListener(LogIn.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1845)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1797) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:945) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1584) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1253) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1014) 
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:11155) 
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.finishActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:4775) 
    at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:6283) 
    at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:6307) 
    at com.example.alarmdrug.activities.LogIn.onLoginButtonListener(LogIn.java:95) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

in LogIn activity

```
public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputLayout nameLayout;
private TextInputLayout ageLayout;
private ImageView profile;
private TextInputEditText name;
private TextInputEditText age;
private RadioButton male;
private RadioButton female;

Uri uri;

// TODO
// FIXME
// we need four field
// 1 - sex(male, female) we have a two item and he choose one of them(male/female)
// 2 - age he input he's age
// 3 - name
// 4 - profile

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

    initialization();
}

private void initialization() {
    profile = findViewById(R.id.profileLogin);
    name = findViewById(R.id.nameEditInput);
    age = findViewById(R.id.ageEditInput);
    male = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMale);
    female = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFemale);
    nameLayout = findViewById(R.id.textFieldName);
    ageLayout = findViewById(R.id.textFieldAge);
}

public void onLoginButtonListener(View view) {

    ModelPerson personalInfo = new ModelPerson();

    if (name.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        nameLayout.setError("name cannot be empty");
    } else if (age.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        ageLayout.setError("age cannot be empty");
    } else {
        personalInfo.setName(name.getText().toString());
        personalInfo.setAge(Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()));

        if (male.isChecked()) {
            personalInfo.setMale(true);
        } else if (female.isChecked()) {
            personalInfo.setMale(false);
        }

        profile.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = profile.getDrawingCache();

        personalInfo.setProfile(bitmap);

        /*

            todo implement sqlite database

         */

        Intent intent = new Intent(LogIn.this , ListForNameActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data" , personalInfo);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK , intent);
        finish();
    }
}

public void onImagePicker(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent , RequestCode.SELECT_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RequestCode.SELECT_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver() , uri);
            profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ListForNameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
List<ModelPerson> persons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_for_name);

    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.addButtonOnList);
    AdapterPerson adapter = new AdapterPerson(persons, ListForNameActivity.this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ListForNameActivity.this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    addItem();
}

private void addItem() {
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListForNameActivity.this , LogIn.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent , RequestCode.ADD_USER_REQUEST_CODE);
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode , resultCode , data);

    if (requestCode == RequestCode.ADD_USER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            persons.add((ModelPerson) data.getSerializableExtra("data"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955034/how-to-fix-a-java-io-notserializableexception-android-graphics-bitmap/10463411