# How to save array of the Bitmap?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the application for drawing, and I have the problem: my application has array of pages (Bitmap), and I need to save/open it. I thought that I can use mechanism of serialization, but Bitmap isn't serializable and I don't know how I can save array of Bitmaps into 1 file that user can change file's location. So, please, give me advice about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the second answer in [Android serializable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002800/android-serializable-problem)

Except, instead of writing to a FileOutputStream, you can write out each bitmap into a ByteArrayOutputStream. From the ByteOutputStream, get the byte array, and put the byte arrays into an array list which can then be serialized.

EDIT: direct link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6640191/606771

Comment: You can put direct links to specific answers. The answers move about, so the actual order changes a bit every now and then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a fancy way to make Bitmaps serializable but, if you have access to the class, you can override the toString method and call toString when saving to a text file. On read, you just read in the data and convert it manually back to a Bitmap.