# Troubles passing an object to an activity in android

Tags: android, parameters, android-activity, parcelable, serializable

i know this question is asked a lot of times, but i didn't find any solution working for my situation.

```
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final String FIND_ALL = "Recipe.findAll";
public static final String COUNT = "Recipe.count";

private String name;
private String description;
private Integer servings;
private Integer cookingTimeInMin;
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
private List<Workstep> worksteps;
private RecipeDifficulty recipeDifficulty;
private List<RecipeTag> recipeTags;
private List<Comment> comments;
private EndUser author;
private List<SerializableBitmap> pictures;
...
}
```

I want to pass an object of the class you see above. Ingredient, Workstep, RecipeDifficulty, RecipeTag, Comment, Enduser and SerializableBitmap are all serializable.

Everything works fine until i include the pictures. So here ist the snippet of my class SerializableBitmap:

```
public class SerializableBitmap implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Bitmap bitmap;

public SerializableBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return bitmap;
}

// Converts the Bitmap into a byte array for serialization
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteStream);
    byte bitmapBytes[] = byteStream.toByteArray();
    out.write(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length);
}

// Deserializes a byte array representing the Bitmap and decodes it
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int b;
    while((b = in.read()) != -1)
        byteStream.write(b);
    byte bitmapBytes[] = byteStream.toByteArray();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length);
}
}
```

I got that code from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002800/android-serializable-problem)

I also tried to make every class parcelable, but this didn't work out aswell due to the enums contained.

I'd really love to see some help for my specific problem.

Thank you :)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if i start my app like this, the method startActivity(intent) simply closes the application. No stack trace or errors are thrown.

Comment: I think you need to supply us with at least a stacktrace. And you might get a better answer if you narrow down your question to the actual problem. Also, enums are serializeable, I'm sure they are not the problem

Comment: You are not marking `private Bitmap bitmap` as transient.

Comment: @VonSchnauzer sorry about that, i edited my post

Comment: @Mrinali tried this aswell. Still doesn't work :(