# Android daily update text app

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse

I'm currently trying to think of the best way to program an app which simply has text and images that update every day to different content. Would the best way to do this be to store all of the items in an array and then call upon each according to the phone's clock? Or is there a better or simpler way of doing this?

If you need to know I'm using Eclipse to program the app.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you asking what data structure to use? How to connect to a remote server? Also, do you have any code - perhaps the xml file you plan to inflate as your layout?

Comment: Yes I am just asking what sort of data structure would be the best to use for this sort of thing. I don't have any code for it at the moment as I'm still just thinking of the best way to approach the project.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the app check for updates each day or you could make a mobile website and use a webview to display the site ,and just update the site daily

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using text and images, I would recommend storing them in your app's [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). These keep data stored that your app can easily access to view or change. You can store text and [bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) easily. For text:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor preferences = prefs.edit();
String firstString = prefs.getString("MyFirstString");
//check if firstString has changed on the server
//for example, set a new String that you retrieve from the server to firstStringMaybe
if (firstString != firstStringMaybe) { //meaning you need to update firstString
    prefs.putString("MyFirstString", firstStringMaybe);
    prefs.commit();
}
```

`Bitmaps` storage is much more complicated, because you need to first [Serialize](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) the bitmap, then store it as a `String`. This probably means creating a new class that contains the bitmap object and implements `Serializable`. There are many examples available for how to do this:

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/06/serializing-and-de-serializing-android-graphics-bitmap/

[android how to save a bitmap - buggy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628016/android-how-to-save-a-bitmap-buggy-code)