# ObjectInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) missing data?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a bitmap.  The answers at [android how to save a bitmap - buggy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628016/android-how-to-save-a-bitmap-buggy-code) are very helpful.  However, when I go to read my array:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
  int rowBytes = in.readInt();
  int height = in.readInt();
  int width = in.readInt();
  int bmSize = rowBytes * height;    // Ends up being 398208

  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
  int bytesRead = in.read(byteBuffer.array(), 0, bmSize);
  // Use array to create bitmap here
}
```

it is reading 1008 bytes, not the 398208 bytes that I wrote.  I've replaced the call with a loop, which works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bmSize; i++) {
  byteBuffer.array()[i] = in.readByte();
}
```

What could be going wrong?  No exception is thrown.  The documentation for [ObjectInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) indicates the only reason it should return early is if it hits the end of the stream, which clearly it isn't because my work-around doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: why are not you using loop if its work fine.its not necessary that it read all data at once

Comment: The loop works fine, I just wanted to know why the built-in method wasn't working.  Also I suspect the appropriate method will be faster - it might be able to use native calls, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. ObjectInputStream just calls inputStream to read the bytes.  Use readFully if you want it to block until the data is read.

Comment: +1. The Google documentation is not only wrong but meaningless. It says it blocks until `count` bytes have been read without defining `count`. The Java Javadoc is correct.

Comment: Many (many) thanks!  I've posted updated documentation at https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/36320/.