# Object not deserializing

Tags: java, android

I have this class from Apache Commons that I'm using to store chess data. I'm saving a `ChessPiece[][]` where `ChessPiece` is an abstract class with `Rook` `Pawn` etc subclasses each with their own coordinates and other data. Here is the code:

```
public class ObjectSerializer {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ObjectSerializer.class);

    public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj == null) return "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
            objStream.writeObject(obj);
            objStream.close();
            return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Serialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
            ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
            return objStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Deserialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        }

        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
            c = str.charAt(i+1);
            bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

And I'm testing it like so, Im just serializing then deserializing a chesspiece

```
                String r = "";
                ChessPiece c = null;
                try {
                    r = ObjectSerializer.serialize(currentBoardState[0][0].realcopyPiece());//Returns the `ChessPiece` at the cell
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    c = (ChessPiece) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(r);
                    System.out.println(c.x);//NO MATTER WHAT I PRINT ITS A NULL POINTER
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Here is my logcat

```
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.example.chess.InGameActivity$MyUndoButtonListener.onTouch(InGameActivity.java:513)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7379)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-06 07:25:52.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You got a NPE on line 513 in InGameActivity, did you check that?

Comment: Your logcat logs are not showing any problem with serialization or de-serialization

Comment: Line 513 is the System.out.println line, sorry I forgot to mention that!

Comment: I found some extra warnings. Every ChessPiece has a Bitmap, and it says Bitmaps aren't serializable, so its not serializing and it's staying as null, hence the NPE. I just need to make my Bitmap serializable somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment by user, **Every ChessPiece has a Bitmap**

The `Bitmaps` in Java are not `serializable` either add a `transient` keyword before those Bitmap objects or if you want to serialize Bitmaps look below links for more help
[Serializing and De-Serializing android.graphics.Bitmap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871482/serializing-and-de-serializing-android-graphics-bitmap-in-java)
[android how to save a bitmap - buggy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628016/android-how-to-save-a-bitmap-buggy-code)

Comment: Thank you so much, `Transient` is such a convenient keyword :D